# How to make a report with each Financial Type as a column?

Tags: civireport

I need a report of contributions which has a row for each contribution, and then analysis by showing a column for each financial type, and the total amount of the contribution in the right financial type column. Is there any way of doing this without programming an extension?

I include a screenshot of the kind of thing I need. The columns to right of VAT are financial types, so each payment is broken down into VAT (if applicable) and one or more financial types.

[image]

Comment: How many financial types are we talking about? You want hard-coded columns for each one?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you would get the exact requirement you looking for but you can use contribution pivot reports to group the records based on financial type via

1. [Extended report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports)

or

2. [Report plus](https://civicrm.org/extensions/reportplus)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pradeep. I tried a bit but could not see how to configure each financial type to have its own column. I will try again.

Comment: Column would be difficult. I think you are referring to financial type of line item associated with contribution

Comment: You don't need it to be its own column if you use a pivot as Pradeep is saying, which can sum up the contributions by the financial type, which I'm guessing is why you want it in its own column. You can also export to excel and do a pivot table there.

Answer (score 2):

The new search extension (ships with 5.30 but is still hidden & you have to install via the api) gets close - you can see it's giving numbers for financial type & I don't have a friendly theme enabled but the totals are there

[image: search creator]

Comment: The numbers for financial type thing should be fixed by 5.31.

Comment: Thank you Eileen and Coleman. The thing is I need one row per contribution, not totals, and with the breakdown by financial type shown as columns. I will provide an example screenshot.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot to reflect what will be in the 5.31 release (which will be in rc from first Wed in Oct)